# CSS issues - Navigation menu

Tags: css, navigation

See the blue background where the navigation menu is. On firefox, the news is pushed down to left side. I wanted to make every item to fit in on horizontal line. So I searched and remove padding from this: `.navigation ul li {
    border-left:1px solid #b3b3b3;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative; /*--Declare X and Y axis base for sub navigation--*/
}`

but the padding between the navigation item is still making space between in. Either I overlook something or it is stubborn not to change everytime I refresh?

Will appreciate the help or insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked it out in Firebug and `.navigation ul li` is still having a style of `padding: 0 20px;` being set to it in the `all2.css` file at line 804.

A `padding: 0 15px;` seems to make everything fit, just need to adjust the first `li` padding-left a little.

Comment: thank you @roflwaffle so much. duh me, there is all same css copied carelessly. thank you for your help.